# How do I fix the git repo to remove a update_ref error for a folder which already exists?

Tags: git, github

I get the following error when I try to `git push` a branch `documentation/manifest`:

```
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/documentation/manifest': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/documentation/manifest': 'refs/remotes/origin/documentation' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/documentation/manifest'
```

The steps which led up to this error were:

1. cloned from the remote repo (github)
2. created a local branch `documentation/manifest` and did some work on it, committing the work.
3. pushed the branch.  Couldn't push because there was an existing 3 year old, stale, branch called `documentation`.
4. Deleted the branch `documentation` on github.
5. pushed again.  Branch pushed OK to remote, I can confirm it is there, however the above error appears after every time I push.  Given that I presume it is a local error.

I've looked up some similar questions such as [Git error when pushing - update_ref failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380009/git-error-when-pushing-update-ref-failed), however this was dealing with a different cause - it was not clear to me if the suggested solutions to that answer would help in this case, and as they seemed quite low-level they could equally well mess things up in a different way.

So, what do I need to do to get rid of this error whenever I push this branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you still have a local reference to the former remote `documentation` branch, because the error messages says `cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/documentation/manifest'`, which would indeed be the case if `refs/remotes/origin/documentation` already exists as a regular file.

Removing the old local references should solve this problem:

```
git fetch -p
```

And if that doesn't work, you can even manually delete the problem file:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/documentation
```

which you know is safe, since you deleted the `documentation` branch on origin.

Relevant reference:

- Related question, about local refs, which also applies here to remote refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527452/3216427

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  `git fetch -p` fixed it!